# SQL Count In Range

Tags: sql, oracle

How could I count data in range which could be configured
Something like this,

```
CAR_AVBL
+--------+-----------+  
| CAR_ID | DATE_AVBL |  
+--------------------|  
|  JJ01  |    1      |  
|  JJ02  |    1      |  
|  JJ03  |    3      |  
|  JJ04  |    10     |  
|  JJ05  |    13     |  
|  JJ06  |    4      |  
|  JJ07  |    10     |  
|  JJ08  |    1      |  
|  JJ09  |    23     |  
|  JJ10  |    11     |  
|  JJ11  |    20     |  
|  JJ12  |    3      |  
|  JJ13  |    19     |  
|  JJ14  |    22     |  
|  JJ15  |    7      |  
+--------------------+  

ZONE_CFG
+--------+------------+
|  DATE  | ZONE_DESCR |
+--------+------------+
|   15   | GREEN_ZONE |
|   25   | YELLOW_ZONE|
|   30   | RED_ZONE   |
+--------+------------+
```

Table `ZONE_CFG` is configurable, so I could not use static value for this
The `DATE` column mean maximum date for each ZONE

And the result what I expected  :

```
+------------+----------+
| ZONE_DESCR | AVBL_CAR |
+------------+----------+
| GREEN_ZONE |    11    |
| YELLOW_ZONE|    4     |
| RED_ZONE   |    0     |
+------------+----------+
```

Please could someone help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LAG` and `group by` as following:

> ```
> SELECT
>     ZC.ZONE_DESCR,
>     COUNT(1) AS AVBL_CAR
> FROM
>     CAR_AVBL CA
>     JOIN ( SELECT
>             ZONE_DECR,
>             COALESCE(LAG(DATE) OVER(ORDER BY DATE) + 1, 0) AS START_DATE,
>             DATE AS END_DATE
>         FROM ZONE_CFG ) ZC 
>     ON ( CA.DATE_AVBL BETWEEN ZC.START_DATE AND ZC.END_DATE )
> GROUP BY
>     ZC.ZONE_DESCR;
> ```

**Note:** Don't use oracle preserved keywords (`DATE`, in your case) as the name of the columns. Try to change it to something like `DATE_` or `DATE_START` or etc..

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for the response, should the ZONE_DESCR is selected first in ZC source ? Cause in the main SELECT, the ZC.ZONE_DESCR could not be found ?
And yes, thanks a lot for the Note

Comment: You need to use outer join as no car is falling under RED_ZONE.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the zero 0, I might suggest a correlated subquery instead:

```
select z.*,
       (select count(*)
        from car_avbl c
        where c.date_avbl >= start_date and
              c.date_avbl <= date
       ) as avbl_car
from (select z.*,
             lag(date, 1, 0) as start_date
      from zone_cfg z
     ) z;
```

In Oracle 12C, can phrase this using a lateral join:

```
select z.*, 
       (c.cnt - lag(c.cnt, 1, 0) over (order by z.date)) as cnt
from zone_cfg z left join lateral
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from avbl_car c
      where c.date_avbl <= z.date
     ) c
     on 1=1
```